# dplyr: lubridate: How to count the number of occurrences by week and spread on daily data

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Hi I have the next data frame

```
    report_date Revenue Day_type
1   2017-01-01  260.96     Sale
2   2017-01-02  540.12     Sale
3   2017-01-03  511.59     Sale
4   2017-01-04  343.29     Sale
5   2017-01-05  507.09     Sale
6   2017-01-06 1023.32     Sale
7   2017-01-07  580.19     Sale
8   2017-01-08  826.74     Sale
9   2017-01-09  753.78     Sale
10  2017-01-10  468.44     Sale
11  2017-01-11  526.57     Sale
12  2017-01-12  419.10     Sale
13  2017-01-13  243.10  Avg day
14  2017-01-14  456.64  Avg day
15  2017-01-15  659.91  Avg day
16  2017-01-16  516.98  Avg day
17  2017-01-17  447.00     Sale
18  2017-01-18  222.70     Sale
19  2017-01-19  129.48     Sale
20  2017-01-20  205.44     Sale
```

I am trying to group by week sum the revenue and then spread the Day_type column so it counts the number of occurrences on each week

the final product should be like this

```
   year  week Revenue  Sale  Avg day
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1  2017     1   3767.   7      0
2  2017     2   3694.   5      2
3  2017     3   2320.   5      2
4  2017     4   3315.   7      0
5  2017     5   1998.   7      0
6  2017     6   1757.   7      0
```

with this code I am able to group by week and sum the revenue, but I need help spreading and counting the Day_type column.

```
fulldata <- fulldata %>% 
  group_by(year = year(report_date), 
           week = week(report_date)) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.factor, count)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The values for th 'Revenue' column for week 4, 5, 6 are not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a logical vector and get the `sum` of it after grouping by 'year' and 'week', and then do a `complete` for those unobserved combinations of 'week'

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(report_date = ymd(report_date)) %>%
   group_by(year = year(report_date), week = week(report_date)) %>% 
   summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue),
             Sale = sum(Day_type == "Sale"), 
             Avg_day = sum(Day_type == 'Avg day'))%>%
   complete(year, week = 1:6, fill = list(Sale = 7, Avg_day = 0))
```

If there is no element on a particular group, it returnss 0 as all of them are `FALSE` (coerce to 0)